# How can I compare the differences between the two files(python Dictionary as a format)?

Tags: python, dictionary

Use the python script to output the contents of the dictionary to a file , the file name is 2017-12-29.txt, the content of the file  from output of dictionary content :

```
{u'AP1': [u'i-001',u'i-002'], u'AP2': [u'i-003', u'i-004'], u'AP3': [u'i-005', u'i-006'], u'AP4': [u'i-007', u'i-008'], u'AP5': ,[u'i-009', u'i-010']}
```

another  file name is 2017-12-30.txt, the content of the file  from output of dictionary content :

```
{u'AP1': [u'i-001'], u'AP2': [u'i-003', u'i-004'], u'AP3': [u'i-005'], u'AP4': [u'i-007', u'i-008'], u'AP5': ,[u'i-009', u'i-010',u'i-011']}
```

How can I compare the differences between the two files , then export this difference to another file in the dictionary format or other format ?

Comment: You have not made clear what the problem is. The comparison, or reading and writing files? If it is reading and writing files, there's a multitude of duplicate questions and there's also a lot of online resources you should consult before asking a question here. If it is the comparison part, your question lacks a proper example what you mean by "compare the differences" and how the result should look like. For these reasons, I'm voting to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate output files with [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint), run `/usr/bin/diff -u` or [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) against them, and you're done.

Oh, and *do* code this in python3. [You'll be glad you did](http://www.asmeurer.com/python3-presentation/slides.html#68).

Comment: thanks.  I  want to store the output files with pprint  save by day. I use this method:                                                                                InstanceMap = {u'AP1': [u'i-001',u'i-002'], u'AP2': [u'i-003', u'i-004']｝                                                                                         f = open('/root/date/'+datetime.now().date().isoformat()+'.txt','w')
pprint(InstanceMap) >> f
f.close()
But this method can't store any character in file . What is the method should me to stored by pprint print out the output file by day ?

Comment: I recommended you run it in python3 but you ran it in python2. And suffered from the symptom described in slide 68. You didn't specify a suitable `encode=` parameter in the course of calling `open()` or `io.open()`. I wasn't kidding about python3 easing certain aspects of writing python reporting code. https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.open

Comment: Thanks @ J_H ,Please help me another question  which is in my answer.

Comment: ，Can you give me a example to use difflib module to compare the two file is in dictionary format ?